# Tell typescript of dynamically defined functions

Tags: typescript

I have the following class structure:

```
class App<objectList extends {}> {
   private objects: Map<keyof objectList, any> = new Map();


   add<T extends keyof objectList>(name: T, type: objectList[T]) {
       this.objects.set(name, type);

       this['get' + name] = () => {
          return type;
       }

       return this;
   }
}
```

When I create a new instance of this class, I want to add additional objects to it, which later on I want to retrieve with the function `getObjectType()` on the instance.

Example:

```
const App = new App<{Test: string, Test2: number}>().add('Test', 'this is my test string').add('Test2', 5);

App.getTest(); // returns 'this is my test string'
App.getTest2(); // returns 5
```

This works as expected, however typescript complains that the functions are inexistent. Would it be possible somehow to strongly type a simmilar situation?

**UPDATE**

Would it be possible somehow, to do the functionality of the `add` function, directly in the constructor?

```
class App<objectList extends {}> {
    constructor(initObjects: objectList) {
       /** iterate over the initObjects, create the functions **/
    }
}

const inst = new App<{Test: string, Test2: number}>({
   'Test': 'this is my test string',
   'Test2': 5
});

inst.getTest();
```

Comment: Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WK8nMw) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, please [edit] your example with a failing use case. Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz yes, that is exactly what I need!

Comment: @jcalz would it be possible somehow, to do the same thing directly with the constructor? I updated the question with the potential modification requests

Comment: Oh, you faked me out by saying that's exactly what you need so that partway into writing an answer you've updated what you need?  Oh well!  I don't see the update yet.  Maybe I'll come back later and look at this once it's completely stabilized.

Comment: @jcalz sorry, tought you already went to sleep and will answer only tommorrow:( the example code provided completely answers my original question btw! this is just some added functionality I am trying to achieve!

Comment: (We are probably in different time zones.) Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WJ8YlN) work for both your original and updated question?  If so, I can write up the answer with both versions if you want.   Or I can focus on just one version, since questions should really focus on one thing and not multiple related things.  Just let me know the final form of the question and I'll answer it when I get a chance.

Comment: yes, although the second part is a bit complex!:) feel free to answer both of my problems if you have the time, and I will accept it! thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the question as originally asked:

The compiler doesn't really track type mutations, so we'll have to tell it what we're doing inside the body of `add()`; specifically, we need to manually represent the type that we want to treat the returned `this` as. Here's one approach:

```
add<K extends Extract<keyof O, string | number>>(name: K, type: O[K]) {
    this.objects.set(name, type);

    (this as any)['get' + name] = () => {
        return type;
    }
    return this as this & Record<`get${K}`, () => O[K]>
}
```

When you call `add` with a `name` of type `K` and with a `type` of type `O[K]` (where `O` is what you were calling `objectsList`), the return value will be of type `` this & Record<`get${K}`, ()=>O[K]> ``. That's an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of both `this` along with an object with a single property whose key is `` `get${K}` `` (a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) you get by concatenating the string `"get"` with the key `K`) and whose value is a no-arg function that returns a value of type `O[K]`.  We have to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to say that the returned `this` value is of this augmented type, because the compiler can't track such things.

Anyway you can verify that it works as desired:

```
const app = new App<{ Test: string, Test2: number }>().
    add('Test', 'this is my test string').
    add('Test2', 5);

app.getTest(); // no error
app.getTest2(); // no error
```

---

On the other hand, if you want to skip the builder pattern and instead pass the whole object of type `O` into the `App` constructor, then you need the `App` class instances to have dynamic keys which are not statically known; that is, `App<O>` has keys that depend on `O`.  This is possible to describe, but not directly with `class` or `interface` declarations.  First let's describe what the `App` constructor type should look like:

```
new <O>(initObjects: O) => App<O>
```

It should have a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) that takes an `initObjects` parameter of type `O`, and return a value of type `App<O>`, which is defined like this:

```
type App<O> = {
    [K in keyof O as `get${Extract<K, string | number>}`]:
    () => O[K]
};
```

That's a [mapped type with remapped keys](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) so that for each key `K` in `O`, `App<O>` has a key with the same name with `"get"` prepended to it.  And the value of the property at that key is a no-arg function that returns a value of the property type from `O`.

Again, we want to say that the `App` constructor has that shape, but the compiler can't verify it.  So we'll need to use another type assertion (and it's easier to use a [class expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#class-expressions) to avoid having to use a dummy class name):

```
const App = class App {
    constructor(initObjects: any) {
        Object.keys(initObjects).forEach(
            k => (this as any)["get" + k] = () => initObjects[k]
        );
    }
} as new <O>(initObjects: O) => App<O>;
```

See how the implementation of the inner `App` class just copies each member of `initObjects` into `this` in the appropriate way.  Let's test it:

```
const inst = new App({ Test: "this is my test string", Test2: 5 });

console.log(inst.getTest().toUpperCase());
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOYdAGyQG8BYAKCQqXjxCiiQEEYYAeFJCADwBcJgATeoQC+APiJlKUpDEwA3ELyQB7AEYArCPG5QAXEgCyIVgGsIAT2UAzVABokIYOfEBeJMAgB3Q8YAUASgBuMklpChB+fhYAaQ4ePkEkAFEeNARuFjNLGxR7KG5MYCwkAB93AFcwVQg0UVFfUEh9aPtucxgIfRQAbWiAXX8JcjDpbgALDCgAOjVNbWmoCG4G8AhW9ogg0JHKX3HJh3pHc39ugHIsJbOkAGp3Vb6kNwCn8RJhnbC0JfK0YCQ2h1gh9PsJtp9vtxfv99kd6LCkAAyJAAJS0yjQUQABpduAASQjRYRY+wvFziHr9UTgqRgkF08HwZTAfIOZhPdxeRjMFiEJAAFWg3H0+UKWHsgvyACZ9MBKtU0EgxAEpjTKBF+L4zpLuGd7GcEQcwOYAUKkKLcFgzv5VSCpBqtTqpXqkABWLakcHGGBTXE6gKBJAAeiDSEh0PoBom9CNJt4rItRTOXuYvqWToDwdD4b+9FdZAZpEa0DgiCQAElgABhZmi8raDFDcGA5BMVgoVxDHa9JC4JBZayoQ5IHFLAkpArpGJ5AqW0oVKo1UTEvq6NUUMkU3p9cHCYGM2vcbkwDnUWj0NtdkZMlkFevcDG+XAYbgoDRaHT6Y6Dd6fShvuZuCmLIoCfYAXwAj8oBtKwMSSBAxl8ddPhMV4kD2aNh2-boACJcRw25+0eZ5BnJXtwNfd95m6EwdztEYPR2OlaWHDxvDYepn0owC9FQUjxDbDj909EEb1ZXBWTcNjj18PkdX0HDDXoY1TQTWcihwiUhRlN0lQ9A8WWUPAICmPBlCwMD8jTbh-RtB8AFVmBqKtaAgAJ9JE4QgA)

Comment: is there any reason that you used `var` istead of `let` or `const` when initiating the class constructor?

Comment: Not really; I think `const` is probably better so I’ll change it when I get a chance

Comment: Cool stuff, I didn't know about some features such `as {template literal}` while remapping keys, `Extract<>` to filter types, the class expression pattern, or `as new` to cast classes.